# Do "formal vous" and "plural vous" always have the same conjugation?

Tags: conjugaison, vouvoiement

In English, the second person subject pronoun is always “you”, but French has two words: *tu* and *vous*.

- *Tu* is the familiar *you*,
- *Vous* is the formal *you*,
- *Vous* is also the plural *you*.

Now, in sense of conjugation, will the “formal vous“ and “plural vous” always behave the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, the conjugation between the formal and plural *you* (*vous*) is always exactly the same.

Now, slightly related to your question, the plural of adjectives is different. For example:

- to a single woman:

  > Vous êtes belle.
- to several women:

  > Vous êtes belles.

Comment: also note: vous êtes allé (singular formal masc)
vous êtes allée (sing form fem)
vous êtes allés (plur masc)
vous êtes allées (plur fem)