# Agreement of adjectives with the polite “vous” form

Tags: adjectifs, accord, politesse, vouvoiement

I know *vous* is used for plural but also for being polite. I also know that the adjective should agree with the subject. So, if I'm saying to two or more people that they're sympathetic, then I would write:

> Vous êtes sympathiques!

And then *sympathiques* is written with an extra `s` because I'm talking to more persons. But if I'm talking to one person, and use *vous* to be polite, is the sentence below correct?

> Vous êtes sympathiques!

In this case, *sympathiques* agrees with the subject, but *sympathiques* is plural, and I'm talking to one person.

So, should I use *sympathiques* or *sympathique* when I'm talking to one person but use *vous* to be polite?

Comment: One person, polite vous: no s. Two people or more, with s.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The agreement for adjectives is dependant on the real number:

- to a single person:

  > Vous êtes sympathique.
- to several persons:

  > Vous êtes sympathiques.

As an aside, verb inflexions are the same in both cases (plural *vous*, or singular formal *vous*).

Comment: This answer is based on this one: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/do-formal-vous-and-plural-vous-always-have-the-same-conjugation. I've just changed the focus to the part that address this particular question.

Comment: What if you are talking to a married or non single person? :)

Comment: @Shlublu: I changed it to “persons”. With “sympathique” instead of “belle”, no reason to mention women. But I don't really understand what you mean. Are you implying that saying *vous êtes sympathique* to a married woman is inappropriate?? Anyway grammatically it makes no difference :-)

Comment: No, I'm absolutely not suggesting that. This was only a pun with "single person" actually.

Comment: @Shlublu: Ahah. Shame on me. This substitution was naughty, it created a pun without my knowing.

Answer (score 5):

Should you be talking to one person, the verb agrees with *vous* [as if it was a singular subject](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_2_22_nous_vous.shtml). This because this is actually a singular subject, despite the polite use of a plural person.

So the correct sentence is, in this case:

> Vous êtes sympathique !

Answer (score 3):

J'accorde logiquement.  Donc au singulier pour un *vous* de politesse ou un *nous* de modestie, au pluriel pour un *on* utilisé comme première personne du pluriel, au féminin pour un *on* ironique utilisé comme deuxième personne du singulier en m'adressant à une femme — *On a du remord et on est venue demander pardon ?* (en fait comme *on* peut avoir toutes les valeurs, tous les cas d'accord sont possibles).